# How to insert x number of datarows from a datatable into a list?

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I'm currently using an existing piece of code that can insert all data rows from a specified data table column into a list as integers. However, in the current code I can only add all data rows. I want to be able to insert x amount of data rows, how would I do this?

The code:

```
var dt = new DataTable
            {
                Columns = { { "Lastname", typeof(int) }, { "Firstname", typeof(int) } }
            };
            dt.Rows.Add(1, 2);
            dt.Rows.Add(4, 5);
            dt.Rows.Add(7, 4);
            dt.Rows.Add(54, 67);

            List<int> ids = new List<int>();

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                ids.Add((int)row[0]);
            foreach(int e in ids)
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.Read();
```

This code will currently print out `1,4,7,54` but what if i for example only want to print `1,4,7`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by making use of `linq` as follows:

```
var result = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(x => x.Field<int>("Lastname") != 54).ToList();

foreach(var r in result)
{
   Console.WriteLine(r.ItemArray[0]); //This will now print out 1, 4, 7
   Console.WriteLine(r.ItemArray[1]); //This will now print out 2, 5, 4
}
```

Dont't forget to include the namespace `using System.Linq;`

**Update:**

```
public List<DataRow> GetDataRowsFromDataTable(int numberOfRows)
{
   //your dt code here
   
   return dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Take(numberOfRows).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, this solution is not dynamic. I made this data table as an example. In the real situation I only want to print the first 9 data rows. Any solution to for this?

Comment: The is a simple example which you can build off. You can create a method where you can pass the relevent parameters in and then you can filter accordingly

Comment: Can i replace the 54 with a datarow index?

Comment: @JamesVH I've updated my answer. The `Take` method will take N of items based on the parameter value that's passed in. I hope that covers what you're after